# Android header and footer overlapping the screen

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

In my app i want to have two static parts as header and footer. i added this in layout xml and using relative layout it worked fine for me. But when i tried to add a header xml separately using include. The header and mid screen view overlapping. pls suggest how can i eliminate this.

here is the header xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="10px" android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:src="@drawable/iconhome" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView android:text="Application" android:id="@+id/txtTitlevalue" android:textColor="#800517"  android:textSize="18px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center|left" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:background="#800517" android:gravity = "center|center_vertical">
            <TextView android:text=" \n " android:layout_height="3px"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

and other xml where i am including header.xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<include android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/header" />
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="15px" android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:padding="5px" android:gravity="center_vertical|left">
            <TextView android:text=" SEARCH FOR PROPERTY " android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="14px" android:textColor="#000000"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/redarrow" android:src="@drawable/redarrow" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/acct_number1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="25px" android:text="  I want to: " android:background="#EBDDE2" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="13px" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>     
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="15px" android:paddingTop="3px" android:paddingBottom="3px" android:paddingRight="15px" android:layout_height="15px" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
                <RadioButton android:text="Buy" android:id="@+id/radioButton1" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="13px" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="40px"/>
                <RadioButton android:text="Rent" android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="13px"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40px"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

header.xml --->

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_height="10px" android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:src="@drawable/iconhome" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView android:text="Mobile Property" android:id="@+id/txtTitlevalue" android:textColor="#800517"  android:textSize="18px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center|left" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main.xml (middle) --->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/investment"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="15px" android:stretchColumns="*">
<include android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/header" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/cell1" />

        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:padding="5px" android:gravity="center_vertical|left">
            <TextView android:text=" SEARCH FOR PROPERTY " android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="14px" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/redarrow" android:src="@drawable/redarrow" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/acct_number1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="25px" android:text="  I want to: " android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="13px" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>     
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="15px" android:paddingTop="3px" android:paddingBottom="3px" android:paddingRight="15px" android:layout_height="15px" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
                <RadioButton android:text="Buy" android:id="@+id/radioButton1" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="13px" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="40px"/>
                <RadioButton android:text="Rent" android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="13px"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40px"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/acct_number1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="25px" android:text="  Property Type: " android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="13px" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>

<include android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/footer" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/cell" />
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

footer.xml --->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|bottom">
<TableLayout android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|bottom" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/footerMessageIcon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="70" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:src="@drawable/iconcheck" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/footerCalendarIcon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="70" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:src="@drawable/iconstar" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/footerAccountsIcon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="70" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:src="@drawable/icontools" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: capDroid, You are superb. Great dear and thanks a ton brother. Its working abs fine this time. -- Rajesh

Comment: u most welcome brother... n also accept answer so, other user can get right answer..

Answer (score 0):

use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout in second xml..

Comment: its done changed the android:layout_height parameter to wrap_content of second xml. thanks.

Comment: But this way my footer.xml is not showing up as i changed the mid part as Linear Layout and footer is Relative Layout. It was working good if the middle xml had Relative Layout.

Comment: yes dear its not resolved.. its resolved for header but when mid layout changed to Linear its hiding footer xml.

Comment: u want header view at top and ScrollView at below of header view ?

Comment: i want a fix header and footer and middle part would be scrollable.

Comment: and header and footer would be visible all the times in an static manner and middle xml scrollable and not static.

Comment: see my new answer.. in that answer set header at top and scrollview below header and u need footer so u set footer at bottom=true and scrollview above footer and set height of scroll view as fill_parent..

Comment: and can u pls tell me the layout of all three xmls. i am taking header as relative and middle as linear( as u told yesterday) and footer again relative.

Comment: first take parent relative layout and all three layout in parent ..1)header set android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 2) footer set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 3) middle layout is above footer and below header.. it will work..

Comment: yes capDroid its working this way. all three xmls visible this time, but still the content of mid xml overlapping header and footer overlapping middle.

Comment: so home is header n three images are in footer n remaining all thing are in scroll m i right?

Comment: yes exactly. header with home will be at top in all pages. and these three buttons with footer.

Comment: but if we do so then the complete screen will scroll.

Comment: its may be some mistake in code otherwise it is impossible.. let me show your all code of layout..

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/investment"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<include android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/header" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/cell1" />

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:layout_below="@+id/cell1" android:layout_above="@+id/cell">
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="15px" android:stretchColumns="*">


        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:padding="5px" android:gravity="center_vertical|left">
            <TextView android:text=" SEARCH FOR PROPERTY " android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="14px" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/redarrow" android:src="@drawable/redarrow" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/acct_number1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="25px" android:text="  I want to: " android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="13px" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>     
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="15px" android:paddingTop="3px" android:paddingBottom="3px" android:paddingRight="15px" android:layout_height="15px" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
                <RadioButton android:text="Buy" android:id="@+id/radioButton1" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="13px" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="40px"/>
                <RadioButton android:text="Rent" android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="13px"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40px"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="15px" android:gravity = "center_vertical">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/acct_number1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="25px" android:text="  Property Type: " android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="13px" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
</ScrollView> 
<include android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/footer"    
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/cell" />
</RelativeLayout>
```